# What am I missing in this Embed & Texture create code?

Tags: actionscript-3, embed, embedded-resource

I am trying to follow the Starling video tutorials by Hemanth Sharma. I have typed the code as he has done on his 2nd video ([linked here](https://youtu.be/MPH0bAWsNw8?t=4m36s)), but I am having difficulty getting the same results.

At first, when my code matched Mr. Sharma's and appeared as:

```
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Assets[name]();
gameTextures[name] = Texture.fromBitmap( bitmap );
```

I received the error using this code. The error stated that I was trying to instantiate a class from a non-object.

I traced the code process by breaking this into steps. Now my code appears as:

```
trace( "Building for", name );
var classObj : Class = Assets[name];
trace( "Class", classObj );
var bitmap : Bitmap = new classObj() as Bitmap;
trace( "Bitmap", bitmap );
trace( "Assign value" );
Assets["gameTextures"][name] = Texture.fromBitmap( bitmap );
trace("Value assigned" );
```

Using this code, I am able to see that the reason I get the error with Mr. Sharma's code is that the `classObj`, which Mr. Sharma accesses using `Assets[name]`, initializes to `null`.

Mr. Sharma has no constructor to set the value of the static variables, so I assume that the Embed meta tag has something to do with the assignment of value to this field.

I will copy my code from that file and paste it below.

1. Does anyone see where I am making my error?
2. Can anyone explain how Embed metatags work so that I can find the error with more skill than I have now?

Assets.as:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

    import starling.textures.Texture;

    public class Assets
    {
        [Embed(source="../media/graphics/bgWelcome.jpg")]
        public static const BgWelcome:Class;

        [Embed(source="../media/graphics/welcome_hero.png")]
        public static const WelcomeHero:Class;

        [Embed(source="../media/graphics/welcome_title.png")]
        public static const WelcomeTitle:Class;

        [Embed(source="../media/graphics/welcome_playButton.png")]
        public static const WelcomePlayButton:Class;

        [Embed(source="../media/graphics/welcome_aboutButton.png")]
        public static const WelcomeAboutButton:Class;

        private static var gameTextures:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

        public static function getTexture( name: String ): Texture
        {
            if( Assets.gameTextures[name] == undefined ){
                trace( "Building for", name );
                var classObj : Class = Assets[name];
                trace( "Class", classObj );
                var bitmap : Bitmap = new classObj() as Bitmap;
                trace( "Bitmap", bitmap );
                trace( "Assign value" );
                Assets["gameTextures"][name] = Texture.fromBitmap( bitmap );
                trace("Value assigned" );
            }
            return Assets.gameTextures[name];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With the code Assets[name], only the name values of "BgWelcome" or "WelcomeHero" or so on are valid. Then, Assets.getTexture(...) will obviously fail because Assets.gemeTextures dictionary is initialized but never filled.

Comment: That is a good point. I should add the trace output so that you can see the string that is causing the error. I believe the string being used is "BgWelcome".

Comment: @Organis, can you please add your comment as an answer so that I can give you the credit points.  BgWelcome is called as I suspected, but as I look further into the trace the string that causes the error is actually "WelcomePlayBtn", which should be "WelcomePlayButton".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You as well might try..catch it to diagnose error immediately.

```
public static function getTexture(name:String):Texture
{
    if (!Assets.gameTextures[name])
    {
        try
        {
            var aClass:Class = Assets[name];
            var aRaster:Bitmap = new aClass();
            Assets.gameTextures[name] = Texture.fromBitmap(aRaster);
        }
        catch (fail:Error)
        {
            throw "There's no texture <" + name + "> in Assets.";
        }
    }

    return Assets.gameTextures[name];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a game and have a similar setup like yours, this is the code I have been using with success:

EmbeddedAssets.as (inside a folder named utils):

```
package utils
{
    import starling.textures.Texture;

    public class EmbeddedAssets
    {
        [Embed(source = "./../assets/icons/stats.png")]
        private static const stats:Class;
        public static const statsButtonTexture:Texture = Texture.fromEmbeddedAsset(stats);

        Embed(source = "./../assets/icons/stats_down.png")]
        private static const stats_down:Class;
        public static const statsButtonDownTexture:Texture = Texture.fromEmbeddedAsset(stats_down);

    }
}
```

Then, somewhere else in my code I use those reference as follows:

```
private function setStatsButtonStyles(button:Button):void
{
    var defaultICon:ImageLoader = new ImageLoader();
    defaultIcon.source = EmbeddedAssets.statsButtonTexture;
    defaultIcon.width = 60;
    defaultIcon.height = 60;

    var downIcon:ImageLoader = new ImageLoader();
    downIcon.source = EmbeddedAssets.statsButtonDownTexture;
    downIcon.width = 60;
    downIcon.height = 60;

    button.defaultIcon = defaultIcon;
    button.downIcon = downIcon;
    button.width = button.height = 60;
}
```

Note that I use a Feathers UI Button, not a Starling one (Feathers Buttons have more functionality but the idea is the same).